# Problem with is_active_sidebar?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I have registered a sidebar with the following code :

```
function reg_l_sid(){
     $args = array(
     'name'          => __( 'left-sidebar', 'Tutorial-Blog' ),
     'id'            => 'left-sidebar',
     'description'   => '',
     'class'         => '',
     'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
     'after_widget'  => '</li>',
     'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
     'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

register_sidebar( $args );
}
add_action ('widgets_init','reg_l_sid');
```

and the sidebar is registered, then i added some widgets. then i tried to use the conditional `is_active_sidebar` to display a message if there are no widgets like this :

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) {
     dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' );
} else {
    echo 'Please add widgets';
}
```

but  it keeps showing the message "Please add widgets", while as i mentioned that there are widgets have been added. So where is the problem?

> Update

To be mentioned that it works fine without the conditional.

Comment: Didn't you have added 'id' parameter inside $args?

Comment: tried but no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this one,because without id we i don't think that will work:

```
  function reg_l_sid()
  {
   $args = array( 'id' => 'sidebar-footer-6','name'=> 'Left-sidebar');
   register_sidebar($args);
  }
  add_action('widgets_init', 'reg_l_sid');
```

and inside template:

```
  if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar-footer-6')) {
        dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-6');
   } else {
        echo 'Please add widgets';
   }
```

Comment: it will work without id as core will provide an auto generated id from the name, but it will be sanitized version of the name which is likely to be different from the name, in this case probably ending in `left-sidebar (notice the lower "l").

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, and i think no need to use id because wordpress states that i can use the name with `is_active_sidebar`

Comment: I tried with only name in wordpress 4.7 version but didn't register sidebar with only name.

Comment: No it worked with me and if i removed the condition every thing works fine with widgets visible inside the blog

Comment: @MohamedOmar I guess the WordPress docs aren't very precise about using the sidebar name in `is_active_sidebar()`. This is only possible if this name has been used in a sanitized form as the id when registering. In fact if you check their source code, you can see that [`is_active_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_active_sidebar/) only searches by id and [`register_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/) uses 'sidebar-##' as default if no id is supplied.

Comment: Problem solved without the id

Comment: How,will you please share with us.

Comment: @JHoffmann Would you please post it as an answer, I was accepted my answer but recently i have found that i should use the id

Comment: @MohamedOmar My comment is not an answer. You already have 2 answers using `id` and the code in your question uses `id` too. If you do it like in these code samples, it should work. If it doesn't, you should search for other causes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem has been solved but i don't know why this happened.. so after using the default WordPress function every thing worked fine, then i manged to delete the args i don't need ,returning back to using only the name argument ...and this was the starting point for me.. after checking every thing worked .. so my be it was a syntax problem but finally no problem with using the `name` argument only. Now i have this and it works just fine :

```
function reg_l_sid(){
   $args = array('name'=> __( 'Left-sidebar', 'Tutorial-Blog' ));
   register_sidebar( $args );
}
add_action ('widgets_init','reg_l_sid')
```

In sidebar :

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'Left-sidebar' ) ) {
     dynamic_sidebar( 'Left-sidebar' );
} else {
    echo 'Please add widgets';
}
```

Comment: This is still not working on mine,but it's great that working on your theme.That's great.

Comment: Yes may be it will not work on some, but we've known it has to do with `id`

Answer (score 0):

I have just put your code in my function file and also create a template to test your code. for me, it's working fine. Please re-evaluate your things, it might be working.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyseventeen_widgets_init' );
function reg_l_sid(){
     $args = array(
     'name'          => __( 'left-sidebar', 'Tutorial-Blog' ),
     'id'            => 'left-sidebar',
     'description'   => '',
     'class'         => '',
     'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
     'after_widget'  => '</li>',
     'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
     'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

register_sidebar( $args );
}

add_action ('widgets_init','reg_l_sid');

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) {
     dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' );
} else {
    echo 'Please add widgets';
}
```